# AngularJS $watch not working for filtered ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to use $watch on a filtered list of data, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a snippet of my code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="dlr in dealers | filter : filterDealers ">
    {{dlr.name}}
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.$watch('dealers', function () {
    console.log('dealers was changed');
});

$scope.filterDealers = function (dlr) {
    if (dlr.name = 'test') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The console.log is printed when the page loads, but if I filter the list, it doesn't get printed.

Comment: What is the use of the watch? If you have a $scope variable you have 2 way binding already.

Comment: I need to run a function after filtering is complete.

Comment: What @ajmajmajma said and it does not make sense with the context provided in the question, also you might want to use a watchcollection or deep watch for array objects.

Comment: I think a much more sound way to do this - based on your comment - is to make a small directive that detects $scope.last perhaps. I'm not entirely sure that will run after the filtering is done, but it will run when the repeat has hit it's end, which presumably is when the filtering is done (someone please correct me if this is wrong).

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here, and based on the comments to the answers suggested, you appear to be trying to modify the data that is being filtered after applying the filter, which isn't going to work.  You might want to update the question with a better description of your data and expected results;  the approach you are attempting here doesn't make sense in context of how angular works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to know when the data is filtered, simply filter the dealers in your controller.

```
 <div ng-repeat="dlr in filteredDealers ng-init=filterDealers>"> 
     {{dlr.name}}
 </div>
```

And in your controller do:

```
$scope.filterDealer = function() {
    $scope.filteredDealers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<dealers.length; i++) {
        var dlr = dealers[i];
        if (dlr.name = 'test') {
            $scope.filteredDealers.push(dlr);
        }
    }
    // you know your filtering is done
    console.log('dealers was changed');
}
```

Comment: I get there following error when I do this: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: yeah - you don't really want to watch something that is 2 way bound @user1024941 , you can hit some nasty recursion. If your issue is wanting to run a function after the filtering is done, you might consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will want to set a `$watch` on a 2 way bound $scope variable. IF you want a function to run when your ng-repeat is done running, you can make a small directive and check `$last`

Something like this :

```
.directive('isLastItem', function () {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            //run your logic here
        }
    }
 }
```

then the html

```
<div ng-repeat="dlr in dealers | filter : filterDealers " is-last-item>
```

Now - I don't know where you want this logic to happen so you might want to `$emit` from your directive to your controller.